# Error while trying to use `Phoenix.Token` in a Mix task

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-mix

I have a Phoenix application that uses `Phoenix.Token` to sign and verify tokens.

This works fine within the app itself, but I get a strange error when trying to use `Phoenix.Token` from a Mix task.

Here's a minimal example:

```
defmodule Mix.Tasks.SignSomething do
  use Mix.Task
  alias MyApp.Endpoint

  @shortdoc "sign something"

  def run(_args) do
    IO.inspect Phoenix.Token.sign(Endpoint, "key", "val")
  end
end
```

When I run this task, I see:

```
** (ArgumentError) argument error
    (stdlib) :ets.lookup(MyApp.Endpoint, :secret_key_base)
    lib/phoenix/endpoint.ex:505: Mealthy.Web.Endpoint.config/2
    (phoenix) lib/phoenix/token.ex:201: Phoenix.Token.get_endpoint_key_base/1
```

This appears to imply that I haven't configured `:secret_key_base`, but that's not true; it's in `config.exs`, and if I `IO.puts` directly after configuring it, I see that output.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

## Start the App

Michał Muskała answered this question for me in the Elixir Slack. He said:

> The ets table is not started, because the endpoint is not started
>
> ets argument errors are pretty annoying :(

One solution, as he pointed out, is to start the app like this:

```
Mix.Task.run("app.start")
```

So the task becomes:

```
defmodule Mix.Tasks.SignSomething do
  use Mix.Task
  alias MyApp.Endpoint

  @shortdoc "sign something"

  def run(_args) do
    Mix.Task.run("app.start") # added this
    IO.inspect Phoenix.Token.sign(Endpoint, "key", "val")
  end
end
```

With the app started, the task can call other functions which depend on `Phoenix.Token` functions.